# Creating a generic select function in Drizzle ORM

Tags: typescript, postgresql, drizzle

I'm trying to create a generic getItem function that can accept any database schema in TypeScript using Drizzle ORM. Here's the code snippet I've attempted:

```
async function getItem<T extends Table<TableConfig<Column<any, any, any>>>>(
  schema: T,
): Promise<InferSelectModel<typeof schema> | null> {
  const query = db.select().from(schema).limit(1);

  const [item] = await query;

  return item;
}
```

However, I'm encountering the following TypeScript error on the return statement:

```
TS2322: Type
{ [K in keyof { [Key in keyof GetSelectTableSelection<T> & string]: SelectResultField<GetSelectTableSelection<T>[Key], true>; }]: { [Key in keyof GetSelectTableSelection<...> & string]: SelectResultField<...>; }[K]; }
is not assignable to type
{ [K in keyof { [Key in keyof T["_"]["columns"] & string as Key]: T["_"]["columns"][Key]["_"]["notNull"] extends true ? T["_"]["columns"][Key]["_"]["data"] : T["_"]["columns"][Key]["_"]["data"] | null; }]: { [Key in keyof T["_"]["columns"] & string as Key]: T["_"]["columns"][Key]["_"]["notNull"] extends true ? T["_"...
Type
string | number | (keyof T["_"]["columns"] & string)
is not assignable to type keyof GetSelectTableSelection<T> & string
Type number is not assignable to type keyof GetSelectTableSelection<T> & string
Type number is not assignable to type keyof GetSelectTableSelection<T>
```

It seems to be related to mismatched types between the inferred schema and the expected return type. I'd like guidance on how to properly create a generic function that can accept any Drizzle ORM schema and return the corresponding inferred type correctly.